# Integrating Doctrine Migration with Silex

Tags: doctrine, silex

I am trying to set up Doctrine migration with Silex but I am having trouble getting started.
The documentation stated that it needs to be loaded and register the console commands, but I am not sure what provider to register in silex or where to place the console commands.

Here's my file structure

```
Top
    - app
    - src
        - Alpha
            - Controller
            - Migration
            - Model
            - View
            - alpha.php
    - vendor
        - bin
            - doctrine
            - doctrine.php
    - web
    - composer.json
    - composer.lock
    - migrations.yml
```

Here's my composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "SilexApplication": "app/",
            "Alpha": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
        "twig/twig": "1.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/migrations": "@dev",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    }
}
```

Any help would be appriciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not stated in doc, but console is assumed to be Symfony's console application, if you check doctrine's commands they are children of sf command.
So, you need a console application http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html
And need to add there some migrations commands: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html
Also, dont forget about db config, you can pass it with --db-configuration --configuration params, or with Configuration class (look for subclasses).